# Files are not copied through ANT task

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

I am using the below ANT script but file copy doesn't work. I have all the access rights and but don't get any error message:

```
 <target name="copyBuildToBuildBox">
    <antcall target="mapBuilddrive"/>
    <trycatch property="exception">
        <try>
            <!-- Copy the binaries to the network build folder-->
            <mkdir dir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}"/>
            <mkdir dir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\forEssbase"/>
            <mkdir dir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\forFCCS"/>
            <mkdir dir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\Jars"/>
            <mkdir dir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\Package"/>
            <mkdir dir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\sharedlibs"/>
            <echo> test </echo>
            <copy file="C:\Jenkins\jobs\calcmanager\branches\mydevelop\workspace\CalcMgr\calcmgr.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\Jars"/>
            <copy file="${basedir}\CalcMgrCommon\calcmgrcommon.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\Jars"/>
            <copy file="${basedir}\CalcMgrParser\calcmgrparser.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\Jars"/>
            <copy file="${basedir}\CalcMgrCDF\calcmgrcdf.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\forEssbase"/>
            <copy file="${basedir}\CalcMgr\calcmgrui.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\forFCCS"/>
            <copy file="${basedir}\CalcMgrABL\calcmgrabl.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\forFCCS"/>
            <copy file="${basedir}\CalcMgrServer\calcmgrserver.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\forFCCS"/>
            <echo> test </echo>
            <copy file="${basedir}/CalcMgrScheduler/calcmgrscheduler.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\Jars"/>
            <copy file="${basedir}/CalcMgrADFUI/CalcMgrSchedulerUI/ScheulerUIViewController/deploy/CalcMgrSchedulerUIADFLib.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\Jars"/>
            <echo> test </echo>
            <copy file="${basedir}\CalcMgr\calcmgr.ear" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\Package"/>
            <copy file="${basedir}\calcBuild\opatch\${opatchbug}.zip" tofile="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\${opatchbug}.${bldversion}.${dropno}.zip"/>
            <echo> test </echo>
            <copy file="${basedir}\CalcMgr\calcmgr.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\sharedlibs"/>
            <copy file="${basedir}\CalcMgrEssbaseCmdLauncher\calcmgrCmdLine.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\sharedlibs"/>
            <copy file="${basedir}\CalcMgrCommon\calcmgrcommon.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\sharedlibs"/>
            <copy file="${basedir}\CalcMgrParser\calcmgrparser.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\sharedlibs"/>
            <copy file="${basedir}/CalcMgrScheduler/calcmgrscheduler.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\sharedlibs"/>
            <copy file="${basedir}/CalcMgrADFUI/CalcMgrSchedulerUI/ScheulerUIViewController/deploy/CalcMgrSchedulerUIADFLib.jar" todir="${BuildDrive}:\test\${bldversion}\${dropno}\sharedlibs"/>

            <antcall target="copylatest"/>
        </try>
        <finally>
            <antcall target="unmapBuilddrive"/>
        </finally>
    </trycatch>
</target>
```

Comment: Did you try running Ant with the `-v` option, to see what it’s doing for each step?

Comment: Issue got fixed. It is because the very file I am trying to copy is not existing. So the rest of the commands are ignored.